# What could be the possible reason for my student credit card denial?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit

I have a SSN about 30 days old and I am a University student and just started my internship. I applied for a student credit card online ( the requirements were average credit which meant I can start with 0 credit). As soon I completed my application and clicked the 'submit' button, I got a reject (within seconds). DO any of you know what possible reasons could have gotten me an immediate reject for a student credit card?

Comment: Which credit card did you apply for?  How old are you?

Comment: "Average credit" does not usually mean the same as "no credit history."

Comment: Your story does not quite add up. A college student born or raised in this country would likely have a Social Security Number that was issued quite some time ago, not 30 days ago. So, did you grow up in a different country and are a recent arrival in the US, getting your Social Security soon after arrival here? If so, your SSN might not even be in the various databases that credit card companies use (they cannot access the Social Security Administration database to verify your SSN), and so you were likely rejected for that reason.

Comment: "the requirements were average credit which meant I can start with 0 credit" that is not what that means at all. With that being said there are credit cards you can put 500$ on and that is your limit. It works like a normal card but you wont get your $500 back for 1 year. They will take it if you dont pay. But this helps get your credit up. This is not the same as a prepaid card. This is what I did and I had 2 credit cards in no time.

Comment: It has been my experience that credit denials are followed up with a letter giving the reason of the denial, and information on access the credit reports used in making the decision. This letter will take a few days to arrive, but will be less speculative than the answers here.

Comment: My guess is that your real question is **how to establish a credit history?** In that case read http://money.stackexchange.com/q/9669/26452

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of things it could be.

First, if the credit card application said that it was for people with "average credit," then someone with no credit history such as yourself would not be eligible for that card.

Second, if you are under 21, then the provisions of the [Credit CARD Act of 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009) apply.  Under the rules of this act, someone under 21 cannot be given a credit card unless they prove that they are financially independent (with either an income or a savings account) or they have a co-signer.

Answer (score 8):

The reasons for rejection are the same for a student credit card as for any other credit card: They aren't convinced you're a low enough risk. You may need more income (or more reliable income) or fewer expenses already consuming that income. You may need more of a banking history generally. Or there may be something else that raises a red flag.

If you really need a credit card, you might want to check whether your school has a credit union that students can join.

On the other hand, many folks are better off avoiding credit cards until they have some serious income. You might want to consider a debit card instead.

Answer (score 3):

Zero credit is not a good thing.  You have what is called in the biz as a "thin file"  You should check with a credit union and see if they have a program for people in your situation.